# RestSharp Issue With 402 Response

Tags: restsharp

I'm using RestSharp to interface with the Auth0 and Sisense APIs. Everything's working fine except when deleting a user in Auth0. I send the delete request as a DELETE and Auth0 successfully deletes the user.

Here is the response I'm getting from Auth0:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Date: Wed, 19 Feb 2020 16:35:28 GMT

    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Connection: keep-alive
    Server: nginx
    ot-tracer-spanid: 21cd87957d9bac76
    ot-tracer-traceid: 25a636cb6e5fd4ca
    ot-tracer-sampled: true
    x-ratelimit-limit: 50
    x-ratelimit-remaining: 49
    x-ratelimit-reset: 1582130129
    vary: origin,accept-encoding
    cache-control: no-cache
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800
    X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow, nosnippet, noarchive
```

And here's what I'm getting in the RestSharp response:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Invalid JSON string
   at RestSharp.RestClientExtensions.ThrowIfError(IRestResponse response)
   at RestSharp.RestClientExtensions.DeleteAsync[T](IRestClient client, IRestRequest request)
```

I'm making a call to a Sisense web service and RestSharp is handling the 402 just fine. Here's the Sisense response:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Date: Wed, 19 Feb 2020 16:32:14 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: sisense-cookieCORS=***************************; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
Set-Cookie: sisense-cookie=***************************; Path=/
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-frame-options: ALLOW-FROM https://****************************************************
content-security-policy: frame-ancestors ****************************************************
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
```

The main difference between the two is the Content-Type directive present in Auth0. Is that what's causing the problem? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Where's your code?